# Gridview out of memory exception

Tags: android, gridview

i make wallpaper application consist of about 150 HD images i add them all to gridview .

it work easily with high ram phones and emulators but sometimes it force close due to out of memory what can i do .

it was 250 images and i reduce it to 150 images so solution to reduce the number of the images is not desirable

any one can help me ?

```
05-04 12:27:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(929): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 12:27:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(929): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-04 12:27:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-04 12:27:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
```

Answer (score 2):

> i make wallpaper application consist of about 150 HD images i add them all to gridview

If your `GridView` is going to be useful, the individual cells cannot take up the full screen. Instead, your `GridView` is going to show thumbnails of your wallpaper images, so the user can see several such thumbnails at once and scroll through your grid. You do not need 150 HD images in the `GridView` -- you need 150 **thumbnails of HD images** in the `GridView`.

Hence, use `BitmapFactory.Options` and `inSampleSize` to load in thumbnails of the images, where `inSampleSize` will down-sample the images to use less memory. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Bitmaps/InSampleSize) where I use `inSampleSize` and demonstrate the changes in image quality as you choose higher values for `inSampleSize`.